# Pandas Groupby except column and take that columns first value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Working with a pandas dataframe and performing a groupby sum, except for one ID column, which i'd like to just keep first value of it.  Here is starting dataframe:

```
ID      color   height  weight
id_1    blue    60      10
id_2    red     50      30
id_3    blue    100     30
id_4    orange  60      35
id_5    red     100     30
```

So desired output dataframe would be like this:

```
ID      color   height  weight
id_1    blue    160     40
id_4    orange  60      35
id_2    red     150     60
```

I realize i could do a groupby like this:

```
df.groupby(['color']).sum().reset_index()
```

But that doesn't include the first value of ID as i'm looking for:

```
    color   height  weight
    blue    160     40
    orange  60      35
    red     150     60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby('color', as_index=False).agg({'ID':'first', 'height':'sum', 'weight':'sum'})

    color   ID   height  weight
0   blue    id_1    160      40
1   orange  id_4    60       35
2   red     id_2    150      60
```

Answer (score 3):

This handles *all* columns as sum except for `ID` and generalizes to more columns.

```
df.groupby('color').agg({k: 'first' if k == 'ID' else sum for k in df.columns})
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby color and agg first for ID and sum for rest of columns I think...

```
  df.groupby(['color']).agg(ID=('ID', 'first'),height=('height', 'sum'),weight=('weight', 'sum')).reset_index()

    color    ID  height  weight
0    blue  id_1     160      40
1  orange  id_4      60      35
2     red  id_2     150      60
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `df.groupby('color').sum()`, you should treat one column differently using `df.groupby('color').agg()`.

```
df.groupby('color').agg({'ID': 'first',
                        'height': 'sum',
                        'weight': 'sum'})
```

Output is:

```
        ID      height  weight
color           
blue    id_1    160     40
orange  id_4    60      35
red     id_2    150     60
```